# Need help in solving for two unknowns involving a logarithmic function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function

I have the following equations:

$$ 0.59 = \alpha\log_2(1 + 0.063\,\beta\,) $$
$$ 0.23 = \alpha\log_2(1 + 0.05\,\beta\,) $$

such that, $\alpha\in (0,\infty)$ and $\beta\in (0,\infty)$.

I tried to solve them by expressing $\beta$ as an exponential function and then using a Taylor series expansion as below:

$$ 0.59 = \alpha\,\frac{\ln(1 + 0.063\,\beta)}{\ln2}$$
$$=> 1 + 0.063\,\beta = e^{0.41/\alpha} = 1 + \frac{0.41}{\alpha} + \frac{0.41^2}{\alpha^22!} + \frac{0.41^3}{\alpha^33!} + \, \ldots$$

Similarily for the second term. I finally end up with a quadratic equation (after equating the two equations for $\beta\,)$ in $\alpha$ which results in complex roots.

Where am I going wrong ? Is there any other way to solve this without involving approximations ?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: Hint. Divide the first equation by the second.

Comment: Take the ratio between the two equations and derive an equation in the single unknown $\beta$.

Comment: Get Wolfram alpha to draw the graph & get the answer for free! https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+y%3D0.23+ln(1%2B0.063x)+%3D+0.59+ln(1%2B0.05x) ... $ \beta=-15.53 \cdots$ .. it is quite easy to set up an iteration to get this answer too.

Comment: Alternative answer ... there is no solution in the range you specify.

Comment: Thanks @DonaldSplutterwit , especially for the wolfram tool which I didn't know about

Comment: Thanks @EthanBolker , mlc . I did try doing that but did not succeed in getting to an analytical solution. Now I know why.

Answer (score 1):

After elimination of $\alpha$,

$$(1+0.063\beta)^{0.23}=(1+0.05\beta)^{0.59}.$$

This is a transcendental equation, which must be solved numerically. Besides the trivial $\beta=0$, there is another solution in the negatives, which you reject.

Comment: Thanks @Yves , yes you are right. The other solution is -15.54.